# how to access variables in the "default" scope

Tags: ruby

how to access the var in the "default" scope in other class definition , do something like this?

```
var = 1

class MyClass
def self.show
var
end

MyClass.show #=> 1
```

and BTW I notice the self in the "default" scope return `main`, what's this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Variables defined like `var = ...` are always local variables.

Defining a global variable is done by `$var = ...`.

Another more hacky approach would be defining an instance variable (`@var = ...`), but this would require you to somehow get the `main` instance into your `MyClass.show` which doesn't seem to be worth the work.

Comment: So main is a instance of Object?

Comment: Everything in Ruby is an instance of `Object`. So you can attach instance variables, methods etc. to it. But it would be pretty hacky to refer that instance in another object. I can't see a valid reason to do something odd like that.

Comment: I should go deeper into the ruby concept, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there's a better way, but being new to Ruby, I'd use `$var` instead of `var`. Doing so makes it global. :-)